# Convert .caf to .mp3 on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, compression, core-audio

I realize this question has been asked before, but I haven't seen an answer that works for my needs. Basically I have full length songs in .caf format but I need to be able to upload/download them from a server. Is it viable to do compression (to something like .mp3 or .wav) on the iPhone and then send them to the server? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Why not just make them mp3 to begin with?

Comment: the way I extract them from the media browser forces me to make them .caf... unless someone knows how to get .mp3 from the media browser

Comment: Are you required to use MP3 or is MP4 acceptable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to [AudioConverterServices](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioConverterServicesReference/Reference/reference.html).. the function that does the magic trick is [AudioConverterNew](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioConverterServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007943-2-SW7).. however note that you can only convert from a variable bit rate (VBR) file to PCM (lossless format), and from PCM to VBR.. so in your case you will have to convert the file from `.caf` to `PCM`, then from `PCM` to `.mp3` or whatever format you want.

For a comprehensive example that illustrates all the steps necessary in doing an audio conversion.. download the [free sample code](http://www.informit.com/store/learning-core-audio-a-hands-on-guide-to-audio-programming-9780321636843) for the book  [Learning Core Audio](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321636848). You want chapter 6 sample code for audio conversion. (anyone who is serious about core audio should buy that book).

Comment: Thanks ! Could you give me an idea of how long it would take to convert a ~2 minute song. Is it on the order of minutes or seconds?

Comment: it shouldn't take much time at all (i'm talking about in the order of 10 seconds).. if you download that code.. you can test for yourself! obviously different codecs/formats will have different results..

Comment: Unless things have changed Apple doesn't provide an MP3 encoder

Comment: @abbood does converted mp3 works fine?

Answer (score 2):

Mp3 encoding on an iPhone requires finding and using a non-Apple-provided library.  There is nothing built-in that will do mp3 encoding, only AAC.

Answer (score 1):

Using Lame, you can do this. Ther is no default function for this. It will also reduce the file size also. For 60 second audio file .caf will take approx 5mb - 10mb but after converting to .mp3 it will take 0.6mb to 0.7mb. Set 'Enable Bitcode' to 'NO' in build setting for new xocde, otherwise you will get error. 
For sample code use this [LINK](https://github.com/rpplusplus/iOSMp3Recorder).