# How to convert CAF file to MP3 programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to iOS development. I have a CAF audio file that I want to convert to an MP3 audio file programmatically. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I think this can help :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607889/convert-caf-to-mp3-on-iphone